# Compare two lists and pass it to View

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

E-commerce website on ASP.NET Core 3.0

There are two model classes:

1. Products
2. Images

The multiple images of a single Product are stored in Images table. I am trying to create an All Products Page, but I am struggling with the logic of matching Image with Product Code and pass it to View which displays all the Products in shop along with thumbnail image from Images.cs and Product Title and its price from Product.cs table. How will I match data from two Model classes and make sure all the matching images and products are displayed relevantly.

Image.cs

```
public class Image
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ImageID { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public byte[] Pic { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }

    }
```

Product.cs

```
public class Product
    {
        public Product()
        {
            ICollection<Category> Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
            ICollection<Image> Images = new HashSet<Image>();
        }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ProductID{ get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(150)]
        public string ProductCode{ get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(150)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        
        public int Price { get; set; }

        [StringLength(150)]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }

    }
```

Want to create something like this:
[image: image here]

Comment: one image per product, or many?

Comment: same for "catagories" (sp?)  You need to decide whether these are one-to-one, one to many or many to many relationships.  Right now you're using foreign key for catagory which would seem to be one-to-one, but then you also have a list of catagories. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

If you have relationships between products and images in database,

```
var list = _context.Product.Include(x => x.Image).ToList();
```

If you don't have relationship,

```
var imageslist = _context.Image;
var list = _context.Product.Select(x => new Product()
          {
              ProductId = x.ProductId,
              Title = x.Title,
              Price = x.Price,
              Description = x.Description,
              Images = imageslist.Where(y => y.ProductCode == x.ProductCode).ToList()
          }).ToList();
```

then pass list to view and use @model List< Products > in your view to display all products.

### EDITED 2

### Your view page

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>

@{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        var base64image = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Images.FirstOrDefault().Pic);
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="data:image/png;base64,@base64image" height="100">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Title</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Price</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: I have images saved to database in Byte. So it need to convert each image back to string format against product code.

Comment: I have images saved to database in Byte. So it need to convert each image back to string format against product code. Their is a relationship. In View, what should I write to pass this list. `@model IEnumerable<Product>` ?? or `@modelIEnumerable<Image>`, how do you write that? means how should i pass this List to View??

Comment: I updated my post. check "EDITED 2". something like that.

Comment: changed my post to fit your screenshot. 4 columns.

Comment: i have marked it but due to less reputations its not being considered.

Comment: oh ok. when you have enough reputations, do remember to come here and mark. thanks.